# Fix serde lifetime issue when using lazy_static

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like to read some json into a static `HashMap`, and am using `lazy_static` and `serde`, but I can't figure out how (if at all) I can fix this `serde` lifetime issue:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref KEYWORDS: HashMap<&'static str, i32> = {
        let file = File::open("words.json").unwrap();
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap()
    };
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17ebf44b1ac1f112c0f64eaa8800d24e)

`error: implementation of serde::de::Deserialize is not general enough`
`note: HashMap<&str, i32> must implement serde::de::Deserialize<'0>, for any lifetime '0`
`note: but HashMap<&str, i32> actually implements serde::de::Deserialize<'1>, for some specific lifetime '1`

`words.json` is a simple json map: `{"aaargh": 1}`.

I'm open to another, non-`lazy_static` approach if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't deserialize to a `&'static str`. As the deserializer goes along creating the entries, the `&str` keys could only have as long a lifetime as a borrow of the buffer the deserializer is reading the file into. But `&'static str` must point to a `str` which lives forever.

I see two solutions here: The easy way and the hard way.

The easy way: Just change `&'static str` in the type to `String` and it compiles. This way the `HashMap` owns the keys; serde already knows how to deserialize owned strings.

```rust
static ref KEYWORDS: HashMap<String, i32> = { // ...
```

The hard way: Technically you can still get your `HashMap<&'static str, i32>` by leaking the backing buffers of the `String`s. Normally "leaking" is bad, but since this is a lazy static, it really makes no difference as those buffers would never be freed anyways. Getting a `&'static str` by leaking a `String` looks like this:

```rust
fn leak_string(from: String) -> &'static str {
    Box::leak(from.into_boxed_str())
}
```

The problem is that serde doesn't do this automatically. One way to accomplish this would be to deserialize to the `HashMap<String, i32>` first and then convert it to `HashMap<&'static string, i32>` by taking each of the entries and inserting them into a new `HashMap` after running the keys through `leak_string`. This is inefficient as there was no need to collect into a `HashMap` in the first place. A better solution would involve writing a custom deserializer that did `leak_string` "on the fly". Since the easy way is so much easier, and there's some stumbling blocks for this hard way, I don't think it's useful to provide a full code sample here.

The only real advantage of "the hard way" vs "the easy way" is that "the hard way" requires one pointer's worth less memory for each key in the `HashMap` (`&str` is pointer+len; `String` is pointer+len+capacity). It's also nice in that it doesn't change your type signature, but there's very little you can do with a `&'static str` that you can't do with a `String`.

Comment: You can also use a `Box<str>` as key, it has the same memory layout as `&str`.

Answer (score 4):

When using `serde_json::from_str` to deserialize from `&str` ⟶ `HashMap<&str, i32>`, the input JSON string needs to outlive the string slices in the output. This is the role of the `'a` lifetime in the signature: https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.40/serde_json/fn.from_str.html

That means if the output needs to contain string slices with `'static` lifetime, the input JSON data must also have `'static` lifetime. We know how to do that -- lazy_static!

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref KEYWORDS: HashMap<&'static str, i32> = {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref WORDS_JSON: String = {
                std::fs::read_to_string("words.json").unwrap()
            };
        }
        serde_json::from_str(&WORDS_JSON).unwrap()
    };
}
```

Comment: This is amazing

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here is how `serde_json::from_reader` is defined. From [its documentation](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html):

```rust
pub fn from_reader<R, T>(rdr: R) -> Result<T> where
    R: Read,
    T: DeserializeOwned,
```

So, the result must be owned data, not borrowed. Even the `&'static` won't do. You have to use `String` here:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref KEYWORDS: HashMap<String, i32> = {
        let file = File::open("words.json").unwrap();
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap()
    };
}
```